# Is there a way to enable font smoothing only for specific apps in Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-10-preview, font-smoothing

I like non-smoothed fonts on my desktop's monitor, but some apps just don't look okay because they use built-in fonts which are not suitable for aliased rendering. So when I need to do some reading, I have to re-enable font smoothing system-wide by checking the ClearType option in control panel. I am using ClearType Switch to speed up the process, but still this is not very convenient.

I'm looking for solutions for Windows 7, 8 or the upcoming 10. So far I know there are applications that modify Windows' native font rendering modules, like MacType, but in case of MacType, it does not remember which apps it should and should not affect. I'd like to find a more reliable solution that would "just work" without constant adjustment. Is there any way (native or using third-party software) to render text in a specified way **for specific applications**?

Comment: this is not possible.

Comment: I don't have a solution, but I use this Font which looks good without smoothing. Even this doesn't disable smoothing everywhere. I kinda like it, because smoothing is kinda blurry. Although gotta warn you blackslash shows as weird symbol! I also use with it a regedit tweak: Win8DpiScaling = 1. https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_personal-insiderplat_pc/how-to-disable-anti-aliasing-in-windows-10/9e1370e9-9eaa-4840-97ed-0fee855e6e88?auth=1